# Exponential family parameter estimation and fitting, references

Tags: references, nonparametric, exponential-family

First of all, I want to express my apologies if the question is too broad or wrong, but I am in need of references and I have no idea whom I can ask.

If you are interested, the question comes from a model I built, you can see some details [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78524/boltzmann-distribution-with-interaction-between-particles) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/80019/grand-canonical-ensemble-with-interaction-simulation-doubts). In this model I have:
$$f(\mathbb{x}|T,\mu)=\frac{h(\mathbb{x})e^{-\frac{E(\mathbb{x})}{kT}+\mu N(x)}}{\mathcal{Z}(T,\mu)}$$

There, my parameters are $\mu$ and $T$, and $\mathbb{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_M)$ where $x_i\in\{0,1\}$ and I have the restriction $\forall i\in\{1,\dots,M-D+1\}$
$$\sum_{j=0}^{D-1} x_{i+j} \leq 1$$
This is, $h(\mathbb{x})=0$ if that condition is not held.

I have the "small" inconvenience of not knowing $\mathcal{Z}(T,\mu)$, so I used a MCMC (Metropolis-Hastings) method to approximate this function. However I face two problems.

- The first of them regards the simulation and the model and I am on solving it (it depends too much on the initial condition).
- The second is that these parameters are not fully known and I have no idea how can I estimate them. I have been reading about Bayesian inference and I know a bit of estimation theory but I am no expert (furthermore I don't know if not knowing the partition function can affect the result). If any of you were able to give me some clue in the form of a book that I can read, I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you very much for your help.

Thanks to cardinal's comment, I have realized that I didn't explain one thing. It probably makes all more complex but there it goes:
The idea is that $E$ is known in each experiment, actually $E(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{x}$. However, $\mathbf{E}$ is not always the same, it represents an external potential for some particles. The "good" thing is that $T$, which accounts for the temperature, never changes whatever $\mathbf{E}$ is, so I thought that I could find a way of estimating it, given the fact that I have an empirical distribution of $x_{i}$ (so, a probability that a particle is in the position $i$) given a certain $\mathbf{E}$. So, in a way, what I have is
$$f(\mathbf{x}|T,\mu , \mathbf{E})$$, but I always know $\mathbf{E}$ and I know (can I say this?) that $T,\mu$ are independent of $\mathbf{E}$. I am sorry for not being clear enough before. I am starting to think that nothing of this makes sense...

Comment: (+1) Nicely written question. Welcome to the site. Just to clarify: In one instance you know the parameters and want to sample from the distribution, but in the other you have *data* and want to find the associated parameters?

Comment: @cardinal well, ideally the process would be find the parameters -> make a prediction given $E(x)$ with those parameters by sampling from the distribution. The idea is that through my experiments $E(x)$ can change, albeit not randomly, but $T$ can't (it is a thermodynamical property). But I don't know $T$ and I have some data. Is this approach incorrect? Just as a comment, we can consider $E(x) = \mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{x}$, but as I said it is not random, I want to predict the most likely state given such $\mathbf{E}$

Comment: And finally, in the data I have I know $\mathbf{E}$ and the marginal distributions of each $x_{i}$.